# ClickOnceDeployment using TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

1 of our customer is using Windows Forms Application and is currently being version controlled in TFVC 2018. We are looking to automate the builds and deployments for the same.

However, ClickOnceDeployment when performed using VS generates a publish.html file which then will be hosted on IIS. The testing team would access the site to download the latest version of the software and start the testing.

### Current Setup

TFS build is been setup and works fine except I’m unable to generate the **publish.html** file which is required to deploy.

### Tried Workaround

I did try building the project from the commandline using msbuild but still the file is not being generated.

Can you help me here as to how this could be achieved? Am I in the right path or am I missing out anything in between the steps?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybGIf.png)

Comment: I don't want this to come across as a "you should do it this way instead" but we were unable to find a way to auto-generate the publish.htm file, but it turns out that's not needed. The app being published is enough to make it auto-update, and it updates the setup.exe file as well

Comment: To follow on, they can keep their current publish.htm file (I'd advise removing the version number from it) and still use that to install

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for the suggestion. I will still keep the **publish.html** file to download. But what if I have to target large audience to roll out the new versions? The end user has to manually uninstall the old app in order to install the new one. How can I handle in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Just as  **Matthew Steeples** mentioned in above comments "`it turns out that's not needed. The app being published is enough to make it auto-update`"

You can reference this article on [Building ClickOnce apps using build vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/10/15/building-clickonce-apps-using-build-vnext/).

If you still want to generate the publish.html file, then you can try the ways mentioned in this article : [How To: Generate publish.htm with MSBuild](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mwade/2009/02/28/how-to-generate-publish-htm-with-msbuild/)

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried using the above links to generate **publish.html**, but when I try to launch the app from the **publish.html** the application wasn't downloading. Didn't work as expected.